# Execute mongoose queries in order and return first that found something successfully

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, bluebird

```
    StopsModel.findOne({stop_lat: stations[0]}).exec()
.then(function(stop){
    if (stop) res.json(stop);
    else {
        StopsModel.findOne({stop_lat: stations[1]}).exec()
        .then(function(stop){
            if (stop) res.json(stop);
            else {
                StopsModel.findOne({stop_lat: stations[2]}).exec()
                .then(function(stop){
                    if (stop) res.json(stop);
                    else {
                        StopsModel.findOne({stop_lat: stations[3]}).exec()
                        .then(function(stop){
                            if (stop) res.json(stop);
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

I'm using mongoose and bluebird, what I'm trying to do here is go through an array of latitudes in order and send a response back to the front end with the first one from the array that exists in the database, not the first query that returns successfully.

I know that bluebird has many promise resolution techniques, like .any .all .some .settle, but I can't figure out which one to use that will work identically to the code above.

Comment: Just use a recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use $in operator to get all and then simply choose one from returned array. Also it means only one db query instead of 4.

```
StopsModel.find({stop_lat: {$in: stations}}, function(err, stops){
    if(!err && stops.length) {
        return res.json(stops[0]);
        // to get random stop use
        // return res.json(stops[Math.random(0, stops.length - 1)]);
    }
    res.json([]);
});
```

Comment: Thought: I don't know how `$in` works but might the `stops` array not contain falsy results - ie those that fail the question's  `if (stop)` tests? If so, then you will need to find the first good result, and also cater for there being no good results.

Answer (score 0):

@Molda's answer looks like it might be the way to go but for the record, the code in the question can be mechanised for a `stations` array of any length by building a `.catch()` chain as follows :

```
stations.reduce(function(promise, station) {
    return promise.catch(function() {
        return StopsModel.findOne({'stop_lat': station}).exec().then(function(stop) {
            if(stop) {
                return stop; // success!! break out of the catch chain
            } else {
                throw new Error(); // continue down the catch chain
            }
        });
    });
}, Promise.reject()).then(function(stop) {
    res.json(stop);
}, function(error) {
    // no matching stop was found.
    // do something with the error.
});
```

As long as errors are thrown, the chain will continue with another `.findOne().exec()` request.

Despite its relative inefficiency, there may actually be an advantage in doing it this way in that any bad `station`s are less likely to scupper the entire enterprise. In addition to the deliberately thrown error, any `.findOne().exec()` errors will also be caught and the chain will continue.